# Do tags have sub-sets or super-sets?

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that tagging your post with very specific tags can lead to significantly less views to your questions: am I imagining this?

For example: I tagged a post with the 'asp.net-mvc-5.1' which is very accurate (and therefore doesn't clutter the search engine with too abstract tagging) but that specific tag has very little followers and leads to little views.

Can tags have parent tags? Where the people following 'asp.net-mvc' also get the posts in 'asp.net-mvc-5.1'? Then we have the best of both worlds: very specific tagging AND many eyes looking at the problem they know about.

Comment: Version-specific tags are designed for questions *specific* to that version. They aren't designed just to tell us what version you're using—that goes in the body of the question.

Comment: I also wonder what would be better: tagging a specific question about python decorators only with python-decorators or additionally also with python seeing that many people probably only check the python tag?

Comment: Agreed, hope you won't get ignored

Answer (score 2):

No, tags don't have parent tags or child tags for that matter. There is no hierarchy. There is a [feature request on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so).

If you search for post on meta about tagging you'll notice that it is already hard to have proper usage of tags and/or have tags that are unambiguous. Adding hierarchy to that would only complicate matters.

Users following [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) don't get notified for [asp.net-mvc-5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-5.1). Users can setup a filter to get a collection of tags in their mail by using the `*` at the end of the tagname:

[image: tag filter]

I think it is important that the users that follow a specific tag only get results for that tag. If they are interested in more tags it is up to them to broaden their favorite list or filters. If you as a question asker are confident that the question is also appropriate for a more generic tag it is up to you to add it. In this way the question gets the right attention from people that can possibly answer and your question is better found when other users with the same issue search for posts. If tags are implicit this is less likely to go well in all cases.

Comment: Ho hell no, i just encountered the same exact same problem, added `entity-framework-6` tag to my question. No one see it. Changed it to `Entity-Framework` with no version. Got answered within a minute. It's not about complications. It's about visibility. Now it's not like i have any impact with my small rep and my small voice... But i've learned my lesson with you guys, I won't expect anything within 6-8 YEARS.

Comment: "with you guys" I mean SO dev teams.

Comment: Luckily you can add up to 5 tags to your question ... those tag-wiki's for EF are useless btw ...

Comment: Ok so i would end up adding `Entity-Frmawork` AND `Entity-Framework-6` ... i'd rather not attempt to explain why i won't do it at all, and will just use `Entity-Frmawork` , I'm not even mad. But men... I have a bad feeling about this